# Curvature in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and curvature in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

> For a unit speed curve $\beta(s)=(x(s),y(s))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , the unit tangent is $T=(x',y')$ as usual , but the unit normal $N$ is defined by $N=(-y',x')$ . Prove that if the curvature $k$ does not change sign , then $|k|$ is the same as usual $\mathbb{R}^3$ curvature $\beta(s)=(x,y,0)$ .

The exercise above was in Barrett O'Neill's Elementary Differential Geometry , Page$_{68}$ . For $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , we find that$$(x'',y'')=k(-y',x')$$So we have $|k|=||(x'',y'')||$ since $\beta$ has unit speed . For $k$ in $R^3$ , we have $k=||\beta''(s)||=||(x'',y'',0)||=||(x'',y'')||$ .
So we have $|k|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ equals to $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ , however , I cann't see why we need **$k$ does not change sign in $\mathbb{R}^2$** .

Comment: We usually impose nonvanishing of curvature for space curve so normal, binormal and torsion can be defined.  Didn't it say so in the text?

Comment: @user10354138 They do. At the beginning of the chapter, they restrict their attention to strictly positive curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the plane curvature ${\widetilde{\kappa}}$ and the standard curvature to be $\kappa.$ If $\widetilde{\kappa}$ does not change sign, that intermediate value theorem guarantees the it is non-zero over the interval that it is defined on. Calculate that $$\kappa=\| T'\|=\|\widetilde{\kappa} N\|=|\widetilde{\kappa}|\|N\|=| \widetilde{\kappa}|,$$ using that $T'=\widetilde{\kappa} N$ (see the first part of the problem) and that $\|N\|=1$.

You'll see that, at the beginning of the chapter, there was an assumption that $\kappa>0$. If $\widetilde{\kappa}$ could change sign, then this would be violated. In particular, we need $\kappa>0$ to define $N=T'/\kappa.$